# how to modify the below pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column data frame in the following format,

```
Z
1
2
3
T
1
2
3
Q
1
2
3
```

now i want to convert this dataframe into this format,

```
Z T Q
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Comment: Is it safe to use characters vs numbers to determine when a column starts in your list?

Comment: What have you tried already? What errors/outputs did you get that differed from your expectations?

Comment: Given `df = pd.Series('Z 1 2 3 T 1 2 3 Q 1 2 3'.split(' '))`, then `df.values.reshape(3, 4).T` works for your specific case. Not sure exactly what you're looking for though.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the sorting is here. Is it sort the alphabetical things descending first, followed by all numbers in ascending order? Or as @JoshFriedlander points out, is this simply reshaping? Is the expected output still just one column, or a 3x3 matrix as the suggested edit somehow inferred?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your dataframe into an array, and then simply [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it:

```
n_cols = 3
n_rows = 4

array = df.values.reshape(n_cols,n_rows).T
pd.DataFrame(array[1:], columns=array[0])

   Z  T  Q
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below in built function to sort the items in dataframe

```
df.sort_values(by='column_name_to_sort')
```